# Self-nullifying objects?

Tags: c#

I'd like to be able to create a base class for a project I'm working on - all other classes would derive from it. It would look something like this;

```
public class BaseObject
{
    bool isDeleted;

    public BaseObject()
    {
        isDeleted = false;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        isDeleted = true;
    }
}
```

The class retains a boolean value which references whether the object has been discarded, and ideally if this boolean were true, the object would appear to be null wherever it is referenced.

I can't overload the implicit conversion to its own type like this...

```
public static implicit operator BaseObject(BaseObject bo)
{
    if (bo.isDeleted) return null;
    else return bo;
}
```

...because the reference type is the same as the conversion type. A shame, because this would implement the behavior perfectly.

Ideally I'd just like all references to objects derived from this base class to return null if the isDeleted boolean is true, regardless of whether the object is actually there or not.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit: As a side note; I have seen this behavior integrated before, so I know it is in fact possible. The Unity API includes a base Object class that uses reference wrappers or something to achieve the same thing, but I've never had it explained to me, nor can I find a detailed explanation.

Edit2: As per GregRos' comment, the question shifts topic to wrappers and stopping memory leaks, then using IDisposable.

Comment: Why such strange requirement? Closer what you can get is Extension method, namely `bo.NullIfDeleted()` though it doesn't makes much sense.

Comment: There is no way to do this. Is this a compatibility hack of some sort? If you give us more details we might suggest alternatives.

Comment: @user2312610 There are a few ways to do that, yeah. If that's what you want, you should update the question accordingly. I'll post a few alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you asked in the comments is to use a wrapper object. If you access the internal resource exclusively through the wrapper, once you set the wrapped field to null, the underlying resource will be eligible for garbage collection. You'll also be able to elaborately handle situations in which the underlying resource is requested when it has been released. The wrapper (and the underlying object) should implement `IDisposable` and possibly have a destructor, if the underlying resource is unamanaged.

You should be carefuly to literally only access the underlying resource through the wrapper. Otherwise, you might end up with memory leaks, such as if some lambda transparently closed over the reference. Memory leaks in .NET are even more difficult to detect than in other languages, though they are much less common.

The wrapper can be generic, so you can use it for sub classes as well.

The way you originally proposed can't work even in theory, because it would require somehow magically setting all fields that contain references to the object to `null`. Simply 'treating' the object as `null`, even if this was supported by the language, wouldn't work. It's not supported by the language, though.

Comment: Memory leaks are easy to detect in .NET using the vastly superior memory differencing tools (relative to unmanaged languages). The statement "possibly have a destructor" is very misleading. A more accurate statement would be "almost certainly not have a finalizer".